# wrong sorting for "name" field in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

it may have a simple solution or none at all but its making me crazy ;) I hope there is somebody that knows something about it:

On my inventory "listing view" I have a column called `"UID"` (I translated from `"Lot/Serial number"` to `"UID"`).

The thing is I try to sort it but as the field is a "text" it sorts wrong ( `1,10,100`,.etc)
Is there a way to sort it as number? to see it as : `1,2,3,4`...etc

[image]
[image]

I am on the `Odoo 15.0+e Enterprise Version` with little access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

With **text field** you can sort on the basis of **UID** field, but you need to suffix number of zeroes of max number of UID digits, like **0001**. Following is the image sorted UIDs with desired results.

[image: Lot/SN sorting]

But, I'd suggest that you use custom sequence or integer field to assign UID via studio.